# SQL copy from other row result sets

Tags: sql

Is there a way to copy the result set from the select query to another result set in the same table?

What are the criterion for this? Do I need to have same amount of columns and rows in order to do this?

I'm not sure if something like below works:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.source_id = t2.source_id, t1.selected_team_id = t2.selected_team_id, t1.margin = t2.margin
FROM (
        SELECT tip_id, source_id, selected_team_id, margin, tipper_id
        FROM tip
        WHERE tip_id >= 26650287 AND tip_id <= 26650295
    ) t1, 
    (
        SELECT tip_id, source_id, selected_team_id, margin, tipper_id
        FROM tip
        WHERE tip_id >= 26650289 AND tip_id <= 26650299
    ) t2
```

Sample Data:

```
tip_id      source_id    selected_team_id   margin   tipper_id
26650287    8            2                  0        217630
26650288    8            11                 0        217630
26650289    8            6                  0        217630
26650290    8            9                  0        217630
26650291    8            1                  0        217630
26650292    8            17                 0        217630
26650293    8            8                  0        217630
26650294    8            4                  0        217630
26650295    8            3                  21       217630
26650296    0            21                 0        381719
26650297    0            20                 0        381719
26650298    0            24                 0        381719
26650299    0            26                 0        381719
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  It is rather unclear what do you want to do.  What does "update" have to do with "copy" for instance?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've just updated with sample data

Comment: And what do you want the query to do?

Comment: copy the set of values from select result row set to another select result row sets on same table based on criterion on where clauser

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL server manage express 2012

Answer (score 0):

```
update t1,(select * from t1 where tip_id >= 26650289 AND tip_id <= 26650299) as t2
set t1.source_id = t2.source_id, t1.selected_team_id = t2.selected_team_id, t1.margin = t2.margin
where (t1.tip_id >= 26650287 AND t1.tip_id <= 26650295) and (t1.tip_id + 2 = t2.tip_id)
```

Comment: why do you add 2 in tip_id?

Comment: maybe I do not understand your problem well,I thought you want to update like this: update record of t1 which tip_id is 26650287 by record of t2 which tip_id is 26650289,and the rest records updated like this one by one.. 
Anyway,if you update the table by the way I mentioned,you have to specify the condition of join between two tables,maybe [t1.tip_id + 2 = t2.tip_id] or something else.